# Firestore rule to determine if the resource has attributes with certain value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have three types of collections in my database.

1. User
2. Post
3. Like

I make a 'like' document such that it has a _user and _post attribute that stores the user and post id respectively.

Currently I am writing a database rule such that a 'like' document is not created if there already exist a document which has the attribute value _user with the user trying to create the object and the _post which has the id the user is liking.

How do I write a rule for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Firestore has any rules that can enforce this at the moment. But I do have some suggestions for alternative approaches:

**1. Replicate the like user id to the Post with a cloud function:**
You can set up a Firebase Cloud Function that triggers on Create operations of the Like collection. This Cloud Function writes the id of the user into an array on the post called like_users. Then you can have a rule that say:

allow create: if request.auth.uid not in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Post/$( request.resource.data._post).data.like_users;

(Only problem with this solution, I don't think there is such a thing as "not in", this needs some research)

**2. Check if there is a duplicate with a Cloud Function:**
You can set up a Firebase Cloud Function that triggers on Create operations of the Like collection. In the function you query for Like documents with the same user and post id. If a document already exists, you delete the most recent one.

**3. Restructure your database:**
You could remove the Like collection, and instead have an array called "like_users" on the Post collection. This will need you to put a rule that checks if the user exists in the "like_users" array, so I think we might have the same problem as in alternative 1. You will also need to have rules saying that the user is not allowed to update the other fields of the document, which is possible.